# If you had to self -study a course in higher math that you know, and passing it was a matter of life and death, what advice would you give yourself?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, self-learning, learning

How would you relearn a course at a level where you could pass a university exam but you had to self-study?

To set the scene:

If your memory of a higher level math subject (like the real analysis) was to be completely wiped out, and you were to be isolated on an island and quizzed in time in the aforementioned topic on a uni-level to save your life,

providing that you were allowed to leave two pages of advice to yourself before your memory is erased, what would you write?

EDIT: Hey thanks all for responding so quickly. Allow me to clarify.

What I am asking for is how to self-study to the point where you could without any greater problem pass a standard university-level exam on the topic. The point of the setting the scene was to create a sense of urgency and to provide the desired format (one page) that could hold only the most important advice. Also, I wanted to allow people to think freely.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Stay away from MathStack."

Comment: "Read Baby Rudin".

Comment: Ask this kind of question here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of the question; if it's an analogy, drop the analogy. Are you just asking for advice on how you might self-study a course that you've taken but remember little about? In that case, advice for self-study in general is what you're looking for. Also, if it's not an analogy, call the police?

Comment: "copy Fridays' notes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What I am asking for is how to self-study to the point where you could without any greater problem pass a standard university-level exam on the topic*

My major professor had an answer for, more or less, this question:

"Any honestly held approach to learning will be successful if the person implementing it believes in said approach."

so, find a book you believe in (or a book someone you trust believes in) and read it closely:

Analysis: baby Rudin

Undergraduate Geometry: Coxeter and Greitzer's *Geometry Revisited*

Number Theory: Hardy and Wright

or,

find a mentor and audit his/her classes. Finding a mentor is a good thing.

Hope that helps.